# Facebook graph api returns only the page id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is the endpoint am calling

```
../v3.2/pageid?fields=insights.metric(page_fans)
```

it returns only the page id. Until yesterday everything was working good. Suddenly I could not get any page insights.

Note : I use page access token and `manage_page` permissions so I don't know where it is getting wrong even I tried giving since and until timestamp still could not get anything just the id it returns.

Comment: i doubt that it ever worked with manage_pages only...

Comment: You need `read_insights` permission.

Comment: I too have the same doubt, how it worked only with the manage_pages permission thank you so much for your support

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `read_insights` permission, or - if you only want to get the current number of fans - use this call: `/pageid?fields=fan_count`